# Set mutable-content to 1 in Twilio chat iOS APN push payload

Tags: ios, twilio, push, apn

I'm trying to integrate push notification for Twlio chat in iOS. One of the [release blogs](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/programmable-chat-now-generally-available.html) says:

> **Custom push notifications**: Fully configurable iOS and & Android push
>   notification allow users to mute specific channels, customize sounds
>   for push notifications, utilize badge count support on iOS, and send
>   mutable push content via iOS Service Extensions for iOS 10+ devices.

But I couldn't find any way to set mutable-content key with the value 1, either on the app side or the Twilio console. How do I set it?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Good news, mutable-content is set to the value 1 by default for all pushes. So you can just go ahead and intercept the notifications and do what you want with them

Comment: I am getting the push alert when app in foreground. What can be the cause?

Comment: I don't know :) Does your app register the user with Twilio when you open it or only for a specific part of the app?

Comment: No it register when you open the app

Comment: I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and they should be able to point you in the right direction or find out from the Chat team what might be going on.